# Sort datagrid in a jquery dialog without page refreshing and thus closing dialog

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Hello smart people of Stack!

I have an issue with a dialog created with jquery UI that loads a datagrid. I want to be able to sort the datagrid, but when the column headers are clicked it refreshthe page and the dialog is gone.

I know how to prevent postbacks or do partial refreshes with UpdatePanels, but here the data grid is loaded like this:

```
<div id="dialog" hidden="true" title="Exceptions">
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="ExceptionsTable" AutoGenerateColumns="True" AllowSorting="True" />
</div>
```

so I cant wrap the column head link to make it not refresh.

Can I solve this somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own answer to this, in hopes to help anyone else I'll post it here.

Wrapping the datadgrid in an update panel helped me!

```
<asp:UpdatePanel UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="True" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="ExceptionsTable" AutoGenerateColumns="True" AllowSorting="True" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```